# In Enterprise Architect, the class diagrams are auto generated, How to avoid duplication of class diagrams of .c &.h?

Tags: c, enterprise-architect

When the code of .h and .c are imported thru code engineering , the duplicate class diagram generated for same files (.h/.c).
Should it be done manual correction or is there any way to do import differently?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined

Comment: @BilalAhmed No, it's not about programming. But SO questions are also often about the use of tools. And that's what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not control this in EA, but rather need to manually edit the result. It's also possible to run your own script to clean the result. That would be just to go through the imported package and foster the diagrams.